# Why is mutual information matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, information-theory

Given $F=[f_1;f_2;...;f_d]\in \Bbb R^{d \times n}$, now define a mutual information matrix $G \in \Bbb R^{d \times d}$, whose arbitrary element $G_{ij}=I(f_i, f_j)$.

From section 3.3 of [Multi-label Feature Selection via Global Relevance and Redundancy Optimization](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/2020/348), author mentions that $G$ is positive semidefinite, but why?

Comment: Because knowing the value of one variable $f_i$ cannot *decrease* your information about another variable, $f_j$.

Comment: I think I understand what you say, but I don't see it is related to the proof of postive semidefinite matrix. Usually people prove a matrix is postive semidefinite by its definition or matrix decompostion.@DavidG.Stork

Comment: Check out S. K. Jakobsen, "Mutual Information Matrices Are Not Always Positive Semidefinite," in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 60, no. 5, pp. 2694-2696, May 2014, doi: 10.1109/TIT.2014.2311434.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Two things: 1) Jakobsen's construction should be easily extendable to real valued variables with continuous density, basically via continuity arguments. 2) in Sec. 3, they do assert that often in applications the MI matrix *is* PSD. Is there some extra structure in the paper that you referred to?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I don't see extra structure, maybe I'll find out something new after reading the paper you referred to.